# guidedFilter using OpenCV

Tags: filtering, opencv3.0

I tried to use guided filter( in OpenCV it's named guidedFilter ) to make a edge-preserving filter.And the guid image I used is as the same as the input image. I am not familiar with the choice of guided image.So anyone could give me some advice on it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use practically everything as a guide. In raytracing it usually makes sense to use normal information and depth information as a guide, so the guide would be an RGBD-Image. OpenCV 3.0 seems to have a limit of 3 channels, which means you can only use an RGB-Image as a guide, where RGB corresponds to any kind of information not just red green blue color.

Here is one of the original papers on Guided Image Filtering if you do have some technical knowledge: [He: Guided Image Filtering](https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=he%20guided%20image%20filter&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=nUgIVt-yLce-oQfgvLWYDA)